# I'm getting connection time out for everything on Tomcat, log says it's all 404. How can I debug this?

Tags: tomcat, windows-server-2008

**Simptom:**

Any kind of connection to the Tomcat 7 server gives a blank page. The log registers as this, there are connection to the JSP pages or to single JPG files that I know are available in the server:

```
192.168.0.130 - - [23/Apr/2015:00:45:53 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
192.168.0.130 - - [23/Apr/2015:00:51:23 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.18.109.82 - - [23/Apr/2015:14:00:59 -0300] "GET /APPS/portal/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.18.109.82 - - [23/Apr/2015:14:00:59 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.18.109.82 - - [23/Apr/2015:14:01:18 -0300] "GET /APPS/portal/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.18.109.82 - - [23/Apr/2015:14:01:52 -0300] "GET /APPS/portal/index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.18.109.82 - - [23/Apr/2015:14:01:55 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2015:14:02:30 -0300] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.18.109.82 - - [23/Apr/2015:14:15:44 -0300] "GET /APPS/portal/imgs/main.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

It's a Windows 2008 R2 server, it runs .NET on the port 8088, and Tomcat on the port 80.

**Things I tried to do:**

Check if the conf files inside Tomcat has been changed. Everything seems normal. server.xml's port and baseapp are all correct.

Windows Firewall still has the correct Inbound Rules. I can even ping the IP and the intranet DNS is working properly.

The websites working on the .NET port are working fine. The problem is just with Tomcat 7.

How can I debug this situation further?

EDIT:

Just adding other things I tried considering the comments:

Disabling .NET

Checking .NET logs to check if it is stealing anything.

Change Tomcat port

Check Tomcat logs to see if apps are starting correctly.

Check if I have a ROOT webapp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are Tomcat access logs? If so, they mean that requests reached Tomcat, had correct requestURI lines (you see them properly in the logs, instead of garbage), but Tomcat generates a response with status 404 and size of 0 ('-').

The blank response for 404 errors is usually the sign that no "ROOT" web application (aka default web application) is running.

When a request cannot be routed to a web application (no matching web application is deployed, and no ROOT application is deployed to route it there by default), Tomcat has to reject it at an early stage.

When request processing is aborted at an early stage (in connector, before reaching the servlet engine, ErrorReportValve) Tomcat produces an empty response with proper HTTP error code and reason phrase and headers, but with content-length of zero.

So,

1. Check your Tomcat startup logs that your web applications have started successfully.
2. Make sure that you have the ROOT webapp. If you have several `<Host>` elements in server.xml — that each of them has a ROOT web application.

   It is sufficient to have an empty "webapps/ROOT" folder to fix this. Nothing else is necessary. (It is not necessary to have a WEB-INF/web.xml file. The defaults are inherited from global conf/web.xml).
3. Make sure that "defaultHost" attribute of `<Engine>` element in `server.xml` file matches an existing `<Host>` name.

Comment: 1.) Catalina log seems clean (but good to know that I can check application's starts)

2.) I do! The server is actually a mirror of my production intranet. 

3.) There's no <Host> definition on the server.xml file, nor there is a <Engine>...

Comment: Re: 3)  So you know, what you are missing, right? Or do you think that Tomcat can serve a response without any Engine/Host?

Comment: When Tomcat starts and performs "Deploy on startup" variant of auto-deployment, it prints an INFO message about every web application that it found, e.g. "INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\xyz\webapps\ROOT".

Answer (score 1):

You can try

1. Disabling the .NET, I assume IIS, to see if it is stealing the
   calls.
2. Adding logging to .NET to see if it is stealing the calls.
3. Change the Tomcat port to some other unused port say like 888.
4. Check your routing to see if maybe it is hosted with a different
   path.

One way to have both IIS and Tomcat is to have IIS consume the external requests and forward those to Tomcat on a different local port.

Comment: 1.) Didn't change a thing.

2.) Logs are the same, the only thing I see are website logs. 

3.) Nothing changed. 

4.) How does one check the routing? Also, local acess on the localhost:80 is also not returning anything, so not sure if it's related.